# How To Communicate From Native Cocoa App To Safari Extension.

Tags: cocoa, safari, safari-extension, browser-extension

Friends, I have a safari extension and now I want to make a native app which should communicate with my extension. I have done some research and it says I can do this with the help of `Safari Extension Companion`. So far I have docs over [Communicating with your OS X App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication.html)
but I am not sure how to implement it.
Has anyone done this before?